# Reduce compile time when already using Git

Tags: c++, c, git, compilation

I am an embedded engineer writing programs in C. We have started a big project in C++, including FreeRTOS, touch display functionality and more. The problem is that the compile time is large (almost 1 minute), even though we are in the initial project stages. We would like to reduce that time.

From my search, I found out that a build server could be installed with Continue Integration tools, in order to reduce that time. I saw that SVN from Apache was a very popular result in my google search, but the thing is we are using Git. So I found out about Jenkins but it has many capabilities (pipeline, testing etc) that even though they are really cool, I don't need them right now. For the time being I am looking only to reduce the compile time.

Is there any simpler tool to use in order to achieve this? Please have in mind that I am not a PC software or a server guy, so some things are more difficult for me to understand, search and study, (thankfully I have an IT to support me) but I have the good will to dig in if someone with previous experience will point me to a right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: None of these tools reduce the compile time.

Comment: wnen you start `make` add -`jnn` where `nn` is number of threads your processor (the PC one) can run. It will reduce the time almost by `nn`

Comment: One of the major causes of long compile times is lack of modularization. Not every compilation unit needs to include every header file. Monolith headers are the worst.

Comment: This is a problem with your IDE and linker setup, not with the version control system. That is, unless all the code is running on some remote server.

Comment: @user253751 I read that a build server is the solution to speed up the compilation process. Doesn't Jenkins include a compile server?

Comment: @P__J__ thank you, but I don't use a command line, I just press "compile", except if I misunderstood something from your comment. I use IAR compiler.

Comment: Well is the server computer going to be faster than your computer? A faster computer makes the compiler faster. Are there lots of developers? If you're the only developer then instead of buying a new computer for the server, they could just give you that computer and you could use it to compile.

Comment: "Almost one minute". Heh, I've worked on projects where compilation was measured in days. Compilation time is proverbial: https://xkcd.com/303/

Comment: @user253751 we will definitely need a very strong computer to use as a build server. We are a team of developers. From my web research I came to the conclusion that we need a build server dedicated for this job. if this happens, then the IDE should be installed and run on the server?

Comment: Are you always compiling from scratch, or do you use some semi-smart tool like make, CMake, SCons, etc... ?  You should not rebuild the whole project each time and compiling a single file should not take that long.

Comment: @alexxx: You might be slightly in over your head. IDE development is nice, but you're probably not running your IDE under FreeRTOS. That means you can't debug locally in your IDE anyway.

Comment: IAR is unbelievable slow I afraid. We used to use it. One of the worst choices developer can make. Everything is bad - editor, compiler, debugger, git integration, silly licence checks on every compiler invocation  etc etc. Piece of (expensive) junk in my opinion. Now we use gcc based toolchains and it is far much better.

Comment: @MSalters one minute for embedded systems is way long, if you take under consideration that this project should be flashed to the hardware often (every time a bug is solved or a feature is added). Maybe this means dozens of compilation times each day and we have a team of developers. PS very funny link, thank you!

Comment: @alexxx: The system I mentioned with 3 day compile times was also an embedded system. Part of the solution is to make less bugs. No, seriously: we had three formal design stages before we wrote a line of code. I might be mistaken about your IDE, though, if that's the IAR IDE.

Comment: @alexxx my last project done on IAR was compiling (rebuilding) about 30 mins. One file change - about 5 minutes - checking dependencies. Junk

Comment: @MSalters how design stages can save you from the bugs? It reminds me one company where someone asked me interview question - What do you do to guarantee that your code is bug free?  My answer: I can only pray (if I was not an atheist).

Comment: @P__J__: The canonical interview answer to that starts with a formal proof. But that's expensive. The cheapest solution is code reviews. Designs and design reviews help, chiefly by separating design flaws from implementation flaws.

Comment: @P__J__ if I will use a build server, then the whole IDE should run on the server? I am not alone, we are a small team of developers.

Comment: @MSalters if you believe that code reviews or any formal way of doing it will **guarantee** a bug free code... But in the practice - very formal organizations generate much worse code than other less formal. How can you explain it?

Comment: @alexxx do not use build server for uC design. It will kill the project.

Comment: You're mixing *version control* (provided by tools/systems like Git, SVN, Mercurial, etc: a *VCS* or Version Control System) with *build automation and continuous integration* (provided by tools/systems like Jenkins, CircleCI, Travis, etc). Although some CI systems only work with some VCS-es, they're at least logically separate entities.

Answer (score 1):

Most large projects run a nightly full build and unit test to identify problems created by new changes. Jenkins is a good tool to use for that.

To reduce time to build in your local workspace you need a good [makefile](https://linux.die.net/man/1/make) that only rebuilds the files that have changed or which include changed header files.

Comment: it is a comment not the answer

Comment: @stark I didn't say that I use gcc. I use IAR compiler.

Comment: `make` does not depend on gcc.  I use it with clang.

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not need the build server. Developers work on their desks, compiling, flashing and debugging - semetimes soldering experimentig etc etc. The idea is a complete nonsense.
2. IAR IDE is very slow comparing to other similar systems. If you have many files in your project checking dependencies (if you have changed one file only may take ages). IAR to gcc/make (from my experience) build time is about 10:1, single file change (many thousands files in the project) 30:1. IMO you should reconsider the chosen toolchain.

Comment: Build servers are a well-established principle, and the idea of shipping builds made in some non-reproducible environment like a developer's personal machine is not what you'd wish in 2020. Doesn't mean that you need a build server for **every** build, it just means that you don't **need** local builds.

Comment: @MSalters if we use a build server, this means that the whole IDE will run on that server, or only the build folder and its files will be in there?

Comment: @MSalters you cant install IDE on the build server. You will neeed to pass licence key problems (one key per dev to be legal). Your build will be very slow (I bet 5x slower). I do not know even a single company using this software working this way.